# What keyboard shortcuts do left handed people use for copy and paste in macOS?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, rsi

I'm right handed, but I am switching the mouse to my left hand to give my right a rest. On PC keyboards <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> work as copy and paste, is there an equivalent on the Mac?

---

**Update**: I thought I was asking for key switching solutions, but that's not quite what I put in the title, and the suggestions to use the existing keys has made me think. The particular problem I'm having involves the holding of the mouse making my wrist slightly bent, and the regular action of raising my hand to move the mouse in a limited area has begun to make me feel it in the wrist, a warning sign.

Regular rests can't undo over 20 years of bending, so I shall stick with the hand change. But keeping the keys unchanged might force me to leave my hand near the keyboard and not on the mouse, which might reduce the time spent bent. I shall see how it goes.

I've chosen the answer closest to my chosen action. @Arjen, your comment was closer but I can't accept it.

Thanks all

Comment: I'm not trying to be a pain, but: wouldn't using your left hand (for the normal Cmd-C and Cmd-V) actually give your hands/wrists much more rest than when keeping hold of the mouse at all times?

Comment: (That is, by the way, the reason I like pen tablets so much. You really have to put down the pen to be able to type. Putting it down and picking it up makes my hand/wrist move much more than when using a mouse. Too bad I cannot easily use the pen in my other hand though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Windows and Mac user, and I'm left-handed. I rarely use my mouse and I use my left hand for copy and paste, irrespective of the OS or which hand I'm using to control the mouse. It took too many braincells to remember two ways to do the same thing on the keyboard.

As for resting, you should be doing that every 20 minutes. It's just common sense. Stand up, walk around, focus on things further away than your screen, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [PTH Pasteboard Pro](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/) and set up any hot key you want in its preference pane. I tested this by setting Control-Delete to paste.

Comment: +1 for mapping *Delete* to Paste. Living on the edge! ;-)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Alas, PTH Pasteboard Pro is no more. It has ceased to be. I am currently using PasteBot which, unfortunately, is only available on the Mac App Store. https://tapbots.com/pastebot/

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to do this after a long research using [Karabiner remapper](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

I started looking for how to get my Mac to detect the <kbd>ins</kbd> keystroke, and based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/960ny0/how_to_use_the_insert_key_on_an_external_keyboard/) answer on reddit, I got to Karabiner remapper.

Once your Karabiner is all set and working (check if you allow every permission it asks, and if you are configuring the right device on Devices tab), you are going to add two "Complex Modifications", one to map <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and the other to map <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```yaml
 {
    "description": "command+ins to command+c",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "insert",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "right_control"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "c",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "right_control"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>:

```yaml
{
    "description": "shift+ins to command+v",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "insert",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "right_shift"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "v",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "right_control"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Important: **use Karabiner-EventViewer (installed together with Karabiner) to check the correct key you want to map on the script**. In my case, I used to swap <kbd>command</kbd> for <kbd>control</kbd> on system settings. But even so, Karabiner is saying that I'm pressing the <kbd>control</kbd> key, so I used the <kbd>control</kbd> key on the script